# K-means Clustering, major understanding issue

Tags: matlab, opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means, vlfeat

Suppose that we have a 64dim matrix to cluster, let's say that the matrix dataset is dt=64x150.

Using from vl_feat's library its kmeans function, I will cluster my dataset to 20 centrers:

```
[centers, assignments] = vl_kmeans(dt, 20);
```

`centers` is a 64x20 matrix.

`assignments` is a 1x150 matrix with values inside it.

According to manual: *The vector assignments contains the (hard) assignments of the input data to the clusters.*

I still can not understand what those numbers in the matrix `assignments` mean. I dont get it at all. Anyone mind helping me a bit here? An example or something would be great. What do these values represent anyway?

Comment: The `assignments` is a vector showing correspondences of your 150 data instances to one of 20 clusters. The range of numbers in `assignment` should go from 1 to 20.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar I liked it very much, the way you described it in just two lines, and I finally realized it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In k-means the problem you are trying to solve is the problem of clustering your `150` points into 20 clusters. Each point is a 64-dimension point and thus represented by a vector of size 64. So in your case `dt` is the set of points, each column is a 64-dim vector.

After running the algorithm you get `centers` and `assignments`. `centers` are the 20 positions of the cluster's center in a 64-dim space, in case you want to visualize it, measure distances between points and clusters, etc. 'assignments' on the other hand contains the actual assignments of each 64-dim point in `dt`. So if `assignments[7]` is `15` it indicates that the 7th vector in `dt` belongs to the 15th cluster.

For example here you can see clustering of lots of `2d` points, let's say `1000` into `3` clusters. In this case `dt` would be `2x1000`, `centers` would be `2x3` and assignments would be `1x1000` and will hold numbers ranging from `1` to `3` (or `0` to `2`, in case you're using `openCV`)

[image]

*EDIT*:
The code to produce this image is located here: http://pypr.sourceforge.net/kmeans.html#k-means-example along with a tutorial on kmeans for pyPR.

Comment: +1 maybe just to make it complete add the code that generates the clusters and those charts?

Answer (score 0):

In openCV it is the number of the cluster that each of the input points belong to